# Can't find my IP address for my network attached storage

Tags: networking, nas

I have a Zyxel NSA-2400 that I am currently trying to move all the data onto an external drive, because I want to replace the drives with new ones. There was some issue earlier with transferring data, and I was on a couple forums that suggested resetting the system. I did that and now I can't find my IP address, and can't access the web interface. I have tried from my server, and my laptop and don't seem to have any luck. I must have missed a step somewhere. Can someone please shed some light on how to find the IP address after I pressed the reset button?

Answer (score 1):

Per the manual (ftp://ftp.zyxel-tech.de/2.new_mirror/NSA-2400/quick_start_guide/NSA-2400_1.pdf):

"If the NSA cannot get an IP address from a DHCP server, then the default IP address of the NSA reverts to 192.168.1.3"

There is also a Network Discovery Utility for Windows that will find the NSA for you.

Comment: I have tried the default ip address and no such luck

Comment: Have you tried the NDU?

Comment: I tried looking for it to download, and for some reason the site the sites i was going to for the download , well there wasnt a download link

Comment: 1) Is you own network in the same range as the NSA?  (If the NSA defaulted to 192.168.1.3/24 and you are on 172.16.1.224 (or something else) then you will not be able to reach it even if it is at that IP.

2) Is there a MAC written on the device? Can you [ARP ping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arping) ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several options of finding your NAS.

You can look into the web-interface of your router and look for the DHCP-client list. If your NAS was assigned a (new) IP it should be in there.

Another option is using a "Network Scanner" to find the IP. [netscan from SoftPerfect](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/) is a free one. After giving in the correct range of your network it will scan all devices and show you a list. From the hostname you should be able to recognize your NAS.

On a Android phone you could use [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en).
It will scan your network automatically with the correct ip-range giving you all the hostnames.

If you can't find it, then the option Jim suggested is still valid but if you are on a different network-range (i.e. `10.0.0.x` or `192.168.123.x`) **you can't** see `192.168.1.3`. In that case you need to set your computer to a static IP-address of `192.168.1.5` (subnet mask `255.255.255.0`) for example and then type `http://192.168.1.3` in the browser. (This is explained on Page 5-6 of the manual Jim linked to.)

Regarding the "Network Discovery Utility". Yeah, that one is hard to find on the internet.
Did you get any software with the device? It should be on the CD.